Generic comparison function for an object's fields
I'm trying to write a generic compareFields function.

It returns a comparison function that orders objects according to the fields you specify.
It requires that the fields you specify are safely comparable with the built-in comparison operators.

// T's fields that extend U.
// - Example: FieldsThatExtend<{a: string, b: number, c: string}> === 'a' | 'c'
type FieldsThatExtend<T, U> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never}[keyof T];

// T's fields that can be compared with the built-in comparison operators
// - Example: DirectlyComparableFields<{a: string, b: number, c: string | number}> === 'a' | 'b'
export type DirectlyComparableFields<T> =
    | FieldsThatExtend<T, string>
    | FieldsThatExtend<T, number>
    | FieldsThatExtend<T, Date>
    | FieldsThatExtend<T, boolean>
    | FieldsThatExtend<T, bigint>;

type CompareFn<T> = (a: T, b: T) => number;

export function compareFields<T>(...fields: Array<DirectlyComparableFields<T>>): CompareFn<T> {
    return (a, b) => {
        for (const field of fields) {
            const fa = a[field];
            const fb = b[field];
            if (fa > fb) return 1;
            if (fa < fb) return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    };
}```

Things work as expected in a lot of cases:

```typescript
// This works
type PlainRow = {a: string, b: number, c: number | string, d: string[], e: {}};
function f1(a: Array<PlainRow>): void {
    a.sort(compareFields('a')) // Works
    a.sort(compareFields('b')) // Works
    a.sort(compareFields('c')) // Error, as expected.
    a.sort(compareFields('d')) // Error, as expected.
    a.sort(compareFields('e')) // Error, as expected.
}

// This also works
type GenericRow<T> = {a: T, b: number, c: number | string, d: string[], e: {}};
function f2(a: Array<GenericRow<string>>): void {
    a.sort(compareFields('a')) // Works
    a.sort(compareFields('b')) // Works
    a.sort(compareFields('c')) // Error, as expected.
    a.sort(compareFields('d')) // Error, as expected.
    a.sort(compareFields('e')) // Error, as expected.
}

But I've had trouble getting it to work with a generic type:
// Doesn't work when the type parameter is on the function.
function f3<T extends string>(a: Array<GenericRow<T>>): void {
    a.sort(compareFields('a')) // <---------- UNEXPECTED ERROR!
    a.sort(compareFields('b')) // Works
    a.sort(compareFields('c')) // Error, as expected.
    a.sort(compareFields('d')) // Error, as expected.
    a.sort(compareFields('e')) // Error, as expected.
}

// Doesn't work when intersecting a new field.
function f4<T>(
    sortFields: Array<DirectlyComparableFields<T>>,
    a1: Array<T>,
    a2: Array<T & {extraField: string}>,
): void {
    a1.sort(compareFields(...sortFields)); // Works
    a2.sort(compareFields(...sortFields)); // <---------- UNEXPECTED ERROR!
}

Playground
Any ideas?

The core issue here is that your conditional types depend on yet-unspecified generic type parameter T. Even though to us it's apparent that if T is a generic type parameter and T extends string, then T in the context of conditional types should satisfy condition of T extends string ? ....
But the compiler is not able to resolve the end type of that expression, because evaluation of it is deferred.
Here's minimal case representing your issue:
function f<T extends string>(arg: T): void {
    type ArgType = T extends string ? string : never;
    const value = arg satisfies ArgType;
    // ^ Type 'T' does not satisfy the expected type 'ArgType'.
}

To sum up, there's not much you can do with this besides using type assertions.
You can read more about the issue in this SO answer and github issue.
